# Timer in for loop java swing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, timer

I build a game in swing Java of cars When I want to draw the cars I have an array of cars that I call in Paint Component, to print the whole array I have to make a loop for on the array...and the problem is that it prints all my vehicles immediately after running the program and draws them one on  Second, how can I do as a timer that every 5 seconds will print another vehicle out of the array?

Comment: Create a child thread to do that work. After it printed, thread sleep for 5 seconds

Comment: While @NicoVanBelle means well, the canonical way to do simple thread-safe Swing animation (as you are trying to do) is to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which is much more thread-safe than using a background thread directly. You don't use a loop in the timer itself, but change which car you move (by updating an index) and draw all cars (yes, using a for loop) in paintComponent. The movement code is in the Timer and the drawing code is in the paintComponent.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware Swing had such specialized components (I don't use Swing).

Comment: @NicoVanBelle: few do use the Swing library since it is no longer being upgraded and has been replaced mostly by JavaFX. It is mainly used in academic settings where old libraries and tools persist forever and ever and ever

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: i did that this is my code:                                                                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
for (int i = 0; i < carObstacleArr.length; i++) {
   this.carObstacleArr[i].paint(g);
   this.rectangleObstacleArr[i].paint(g);
  }

Comment: @jony: please no code in comments since it looses formatting making it difficult to read and because it is too important to be buried in comments. If you have pertinent code to post (and preferably a decent [mre], post it as code-formatted text in your question.